# feed drupal 8 custom block with json decode content

Tags: theming, 8

i have created a block and try to feed it with WS request

```
function amu_news_preprocess_block(&$variables)
 {

  if ($variables['elements']['#configuration']['id'] == 'amu_news_block') {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();     
    $url = 'mywebserviceretrievingjson.org';
    $response = $client->request('GET', $url);

    //this display json:
    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    // this generate server error although $content contains array of nodes as expected:
    //    $content=json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);


    $variables['elements']['content'] = $content;
    //why do i need to do that next line ? i dunno but this makes json content display on my twig template:
    $variables['content'] = $variables['elements']['content'];
}
}
```

i am trying to display feeds as array or object

Comment: This is very similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182315/how-to-print-json-data-from-facebook-in-a-block/182416#182416

Comment: i believe this code worked but the twig variable treatment was not the same between a json and an array

Comment: This doesn't belong into preprocess but in the build() method, as you figured out in the other question I think.